# keyboard image coding - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

My code is an image of a keyboard coding. When I did the touch on the caps I had two letters—one upper-case and one lower-case.

```
  public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
       final float x = event.getX();
                final float y = event.getY();
    if (imagepassword.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.keyboardpfe2).getConstantState()) /*test on an image*/ {
                    if (x > 0 && x < 100 && y > 170 && y < 310) {
                        login.setText(login.getText() + "Q");
                        imagepassword.setImageResource(R.drawable.keyboardpfe);}
    if (imagepassword.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.keyboardpfe).getConstantState()) {
                if (x > 0 && x < 100 && y > 170 && y < 310) {
                    login.setText(login.getText() + "q");}}
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question as follows:
- Explain what you are doing clearly and what you are intending to achieve
- Explain the problem you encountered
- List what you tried to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

put `else if`

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {
      if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            final float x = event.getX();
            final float y = event.getY();
      if (imagepassword.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.keyboardpfe2).getConstantState()) /*test on an image*/ {
          if (x > 0 && x < 100 && y > 170 && y < 310) {
              login.setText(login.getText() + "Q");
              imagepassword.setImageResource(R.drawable.keyboardpfe);
          }
      else if (imagepassword.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.keyboardpfe).getConstantState()) {
          if (x > 0 && x < 100 && y > 170 && y < 310) {
                login.setText(login.getText() + "q");
          }
      }
}
```